# How to develop screen resolution independent smart device application in C#?

Tags: c#, screen, smartphone

I am developing smart device application in C#. I am developing this application for 240*320 screen resolution. I want to make this application screen resolution independent so that it can run on different mobile devices with different screen resolutions. Currently I am testing my application on different emulators for platform- Pocket PC 2003, Windows mobile 6 standard SDK & Windows Mobile 6 professional SDK . When I run the application on emulator for 240*320 screen resolution or less than that it works well ( only it provide the horizontal & vertical scrall bar in case of resolution less tha 240*320). If I run my application on emulator with more than 240*320 screen resolution its User Inferface gets badly affected.  How to make the smart device application screen resolution independent ? Can you provide me the code or link through which i can resolve the above issue? Is there any setting for making the application screen resolution independent?

Comment: I seem to remember Visual Basic on the desktop let you zoom views to a percentage scale.  I don't know about mobile though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the Docking or Anchoring techniques.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/MOB4DEVS03.aspx